# Trying to use exports.create from another module in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to use code from one module in another module.

Module1Directory has the following files:

Module1.js

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
     function something(){}
}
```

Index.js:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./Module1.js');

var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', controller.create);

module.exports = router;
```

Module2Directory has the following files:

Module2.js

```
var confusing = require('../Module1Directory/Module1.js');

exports.create = function(req, res){
     confusing.create.something();
}
```

Index.js:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./Module2.js');

var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', controller.create);

module.exports = router;
```

the function something run in Module2 returns *'undefined is not a function'* in the terminal.  What's wrong?

Comment: try using module.exports.create

Comment: where? in module 1 or module 2?

Comment: In module 1. module.exports.create...

Comment: @tehnuty: `exports` is the top-level thing, you don't use `module`.

Comment: Are you really sure you want `create` to be a function?

Comment: Your edit suggests, yes, you want `create` to be a function. If so, my answer shows how to do that. It's unclear what `something` is meant to be/do, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `create` is a *function*, but you're treating it as a non-function object. You'd have to *call* it, and it would have to return an object with a `something` property:

`Module1.js`:

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
     function something(){}

     return {something: something};     // <===
};
```

`Module2.js`

```
var confusing = require('../Module1Directory/Module1.js');

exports.create = function(req, res){
     confusing.create(req, res).something();
     //              ^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

Comment: This is progress. Thank you. The next problem I'm having is that req is the object I'm sending but req.body is how my variables are named.  When I pass something from the front end to the back end it comes into a post as req.body but when I pass it from the backend it comes in as req.  Do you have any insight on this?

Comment: @rashadb: I'm afraid not, stacking middlewares in NodeJS isn't something I've done much of.